# In Liquid, how can I concatenate strings resulting from if cases?

Tags: liquid, markup

Brief:

I'm using Liquid in Zendesk to dynamically create automatic responses to customer inquiries. I use Liquid to generate a (theoretically) random number using the modulo function and some aspect of the ticket. I then entered if cases that would yield a sentence. When combined, the sentences become the entire response.

Issue:

Everything works fine, except that each sentence is being returned on a new line, which is expected behavior. How can I combine them into a paragraph?

Sample output:

Joe, we're ecstatic to hear from you!

We're busy answering messages, I'm very sorry for the delay replying to your question.

We will get back to you in a jiffy.

Thanks for being so patient.

Sample of the code:

```
{% assign ticketid = ticket.id | modulo:20 %}
{% case ticketid %} 
{% when 0 %}
Hello {{ticket.requester.first_name}}.
{% endcase %}
{% assign lendescr = ticket.description | size | modulo:20 %}
{% case lendescr %}
{% when 0 %}
Sorry, but we're a bit delayed in answering requests.
{% endcase %}
```

So if both variables were equal to zero, the first 2 lines would appear as such:

Hello Bob.

Sorry, but we're a bit delayed in answering requests.

I want it to return:

Hello Bob. Sorry, but we're a bit delayed in answering requests.

So how can I make this into a concatenated string instead of separate lines? Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Solved, kind of. I changed the results to assign a string to a variable, then concatenated the variables using append. Now I have an issue with it generating whitespace at the beginning where the logic would be. How do I stop it from making this whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

See Liquid Reference > Basics > Whitespace Control: 
https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/whitespace

You would change some / all of your tags from `{% .. %}` to `{%- .. -%}`